# Datepickk library not define using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

i'm building a calendar module on my current project using Datepickk library. But when i tried to initialize it, it always show "ReferenceError: Datepickk is not defined" error.

this is my code:
 - calendar.js

```
    const schoolCalendar = () => {

       //Initialize
       var datepicker = new Datepickk();
       datepicker.show();
    }

    export default schoolCalendar;
```

- main.js file

```
   import schoolLogin from "./pages/school/login/_login";
   import schoolCalendar from "./pages/school/_calendar/_calendar";

   function loadOnDasboardPages() 
      let pageLocation = document.body.getAttribute('data-dashboard');

      switch (pageLocation) {
         case "teacher":
            dashboardTeacher();
            break;
            case "school-calendar":
               schoolCalendar();
               break;
         default:
            return null;
      }
   }
   loadOnDasboardPages();
```

the error:
`"ReferenceError: Datepickk is not defined"` appeared on console when i tried to run it.
what is the cause for this error as i already followed its documentation.
How do i fix this issue? so i can use this library for my project.
thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How do you import `Datepickk` in calendar.js?

Comment: thanks @Blaz for your response, i thought by using ```var datepicker = new Datepickk();```, i can start working with this library. Did i missed something? if yes, may i know how to use/import this library to my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use `npm` to install `datepickk`, you need to import the library to use it. The same goes for any library installed with npm.

So your file calendar.js should look like:

```
    import Datepickk from 'datepickk';

    const schoolCalendar = () => {

       //Initialize
       var datepicker = new Datepickk();
       datepicker.show();
    }

    export default schoolCalendar;
```

or

```
    import "datepickk/dist/datepickk.css";
    import Datepickk from "datepickk/dist/datepickk";

    const schoolCalendar = () => {

       //Initialize
       var datepicker = new Datepickk();
       datepicker.show();
    }

    export default schoolCalendar;
```

Sample code: https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-shannon-ikt4e

Comment: hi @blaz, it seems working now but another issue: ```ERROR in ./node_modules/datepickk/src/css/datepickk.less 3:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| /*Main color*/
| /*Datepickk*/
> .d-noscroll {
|   overflow: hidden;
| } ``` i tried installing less-loader to fix this but the error still happens.

Comment: That is another issue entirely. It means that you need a babel loader for .less file. It is more related to how you set up the project. There is a dirty solution for it, but I don't recommend - please check my update

Comment: Above update might not work if your project setup does not have a loader for css - so in the end, please look up to how to add necessary loaders for your project.

Comment: thank you very much @Blaz, i learned important stuffs today. I'm still getting the same issue although i have installed less-loader ```{
        test: /\.(less)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'css-loader' 
        }, {
          loader: 'less-loader'
        }]
      }``` I will use your example code right now then follow your advice on cleaner import down the line.